# Upload TXT or CSV file Using WinHTTP and LotusScript

Tags: file, upload, winhttp, lotusscript

```
'Declare long
Dim lng_resolveTimeout, lng_connectTimeout, lng_sendTimeout,
lng_receiveTimeout As Long

'Declare integer
Dim int_serverCredentials As Integer

'Declare variants
Dim var_submitObject As Variant

'Set values
int_serverCredentials = 0

lng_resolveTimeout = 120000 'miliseconds = 2 minutes
lng_connectTimeout = 1200000
lng_sendTimeout = 1200000
lng_receiveTimeout = 1200000

'Create HTTP object
Set var_submitObject = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
Call var_submitObject.SetTimeouts(lng_resolveTimeout,
lng_connectTimeout, lng_sendTimeout, lng_receiveTimeout)

'Standards for this post
%REM
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary={boundary}
{boundary}
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="{filename}"
Content-Type: text/plain
{contents}
{boundary}--
%END REM

'Set post parameters
Call var_submitObject.open("POST", str_url, False)
Call var_submitObject.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml")
Call var_submitObject.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " & str_auth)
Call var_submitObject.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=b1")
str_boundary = |--b1| & Chr(13) &_
|Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="name.txt"| & Chr(13) &_
|Content-Type: text/plain| & Chr(13) &_
str_fileContent & |b1--|
'Send the HTTP request
Call var_submitObject.Send(str_boundary)
'Wait for the answer and set object as returned value for further validation
Call var_submitObject.WaitForResponse
Set submitHTTP = var_submitObject
'Clear memory
Set var_submitObject = Nothing
```

Questions:

1. How to specify the "boundary" and send the file content correctly as a TXT file upload?
2. How to specify the line break for this boundary content?

Answer (score 1):

Re the EOL question, you specify `Chr(13)` but that's not a complete line-feed in Windows (I assume you're using Windows based on the winhttp tag you also mention). An EOL entity in Windows is `CR + LF` where a carriage return is Chr(13) and a line-feed is Chr(10).

With regards text, you specify that in your content-type.